# How do I set environment variables for Rails server in Aptana Studio Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, aptana, aptana3

How do I change the environment variables for the Rails server in Aptana Studio plugin? It doesn't work like the other Eclipse plugins and doesn't use Run Configurations. This is as far as I've gotten, but there is no option for the environment.

[minus http://i.minus.com/ihQWP9Pnp0Ruu.png](http://i.minus.com/ihQWP9Pnp0Ruu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how when I needed to set the path to a certificate authority file. You have to set the environment before starting Eclipse. You can do this from the Windows dialog

[minus http://i.minus.com/ixQ6WmcwGt4Ha.png](http://i.minus.com/ixQ6WmcwGt4Ha.png)

Since I wanted to set financial API keys, I didn't want it to be available to every program. So I had to

1. Start command.com as Administrator.
2. Create \Program Files\Java\eclipse-kepler-4.3\eclipse.bat
3. Set the environment I wanted `set MYENV=value` and run eclipse.exe.
4. This pops up a window when you execute the .bat. So...
5. Create a shortcut and set the window to minimized.
6. Add the shortcut to your Start Menu.